# How to convert a xml services code into yaml?

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

I want to use a code snippet from this answer but cant use the xml code in my services.yml file.

[FOS Comment permissions with ACL and Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005142/fos-comment-permissions-with-acl-and-roles)

I tried several converters but they couldnt help me yet.

Any help how to convert this in yaml? Thank you :)

```
<service id="application.sonata.comment.acl.comment.roles" class="Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\Acl\RoleCommentAcl" public="false">
<argument type="service" id="security.context" />
<argument>IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY</argument> <!-- Create role -->
<argument>IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY</argument> <!-- View role -->
<argument>ROLE_ADMIN</argument> <!-- Edit role -->
<argument>ROLE_ADMIN</argument> <!-- Delete role -->
<argument>%fos_comment.model.comment.class%</argument>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
application.sonata.comment.acl.comment.roles:
    class: Application\Sonata\CommentBundle\Acl\RoleCommentAcl
    public: false
    arguments:
        - @security.context
        - IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY         # Create role
        - IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY   # View role
        - ROLE_ADMIN                     # Edit role
        - ROLE_ADMIN                     # Delete role
        - %fos_comment.model.comment.class%
```